# Unable to boot into LVM/LUKS on second disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lvm, luks

I have one Linux OS (Linux Mint) installed on my first hard disk inside a LUKS partition and now I'm trying to install a dual boot scenario on a second disk.
I successfully installed Ubuntu into a LUKS partition on the second disk (sdb) with these partitions (among others):

```
sdb1 boot
sdb4 LUKS
```

I used LVM inside the LUKS partition to create these logical partitions (among others):

```
vg-lvroot1
swap
```

I unlocked the LUKS partition and installed Ubuntu into `vg-lvroot1` (as `/`) and `sdb1` (as boot) and updated the boot loader on `sdb`. Then I ran the normal dance:

```
$ mount /dev/mapper/vg-lvroot1 /mnt
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
$ mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
$ mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$ chroot /mnt
$ echo "sdb4_crypt UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdb4) none luks" >/etc/crypttab
$ update-initramfs -u
$ grub-install /dev/sdb
$ grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
$ update-grub
```

When I reboot and use the BIOS to select my second disk, I get the expected grub prompt for Ubuntu. But when I choose it it starts the boot process, but instead of prompting for the LUKS key, it eventually drops down into a busybox prompt.

What did I do wrong? I have used this procedure many times on my first disk with various Debian-based OSes including Ubuntu and including another install into a separate boot partition using a different LVM root partition inside LUKS, with no problem, but something seems to be wrong when I do this procedure with my second disk.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem involved the way the LUKS encrypted partition was unlocked.  I had be using the GUI tools to unlock it, by clicking and entering the passphrase.  My guess is that this confuses things somehow by assigning a different label to the encrypted partition.  It appears that the encrypted partition really does need to be unlocked properly using `cryptsetup luksOpen ...`.

Additionally, it is important to have the encrypted partition unlocked when running `update-initramfs` and `update-grub` (I made this mistake several times while trying to fix the original problem).